# XML Parsing to fetch links, in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing

I know XML parsing has been explained many times on the forum, but I've got an XML data, which I'm unable to parse in my project in Objective-C.

Following is the XML I have :

```
<cimpleML xmlns="http://www.example.org/cimple">
<Analytics segmentDelay="15000" serverUrl="http://adjingo.2cimple.com/adserver/analytics.xml" id="1"/>
<Campaign videoId="http://adjingo.s3.amazonaws.com/151/Video/6337.flv" publisherId="151" id="4151"/>
<Template orientation="vertical" bgGradientAlphas="" bgGradientRatio="0.5" bgGradientColors="0" bgColor="0" height="435.0" width="470.0" id="4375">
<div borderAlpha="1.0" borderColor="0" bgColor="0xffffff" splashResize="false" splashImage="" alpha="1.0" height="435.0" width="470.0" y="0.0" x="0.0" id="4352"/>
<videoCanvas actual_width="0.0" actual_height="0.0" bgColor="0" height="235.0" width="460.0" y="5.0" x="4.0" id="0"/>
<girgit>
<adunit transitionEffectDuration="1.0" transitionEffect="alpha" showOnce="false" duration="10.0" id="9392">
<displayApp panelType="normal" panelActivation="null" panel="right" divId="4352">
<renderingData id="6832">
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><application backgroundAlpha="0" backgroundColor="0xD6EDFF" backgroundGradientAlpha="[]" backgroundGradientColor="[]" height="295" width="211"><image id="12771" click="getURL('http://adjingo.2cimple.com/adserver/urlmap/redirectUrl/ac0cb032-4144-48b0-b4d9-aa5d9944a743?campId=4151')" height='435.0' width='470.0' x='0.0' y='0.0' source='http://adjingo.2cimple.com/content/151/Image/6291.jpg' ><keyframes><keyframe x="0.0" y="0.0" width="470.0" height="435.0" alpha="1.0" framenumber="0" /></keyframes></image></application>]]>
</renderingData>
</displayApp>
</adunit>
<adunit transitionEffectDuration="1.0" transitionEffect="alpha" showOnce="false" duration="10.0" id="9393">
<displayApp panelType="normal" panelActivation="null" panel="right" divId="4352">
<renderingData id="6833">
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><application backgroundAlpha="0" backgroundColor="0xD6EDFF" backgroundGradientAlpha="[]" backgroundGradientColor="[]" height="295" width="211"><image id="12772" click="getURL('http://adjingo.2cimple.com/adserver/urlmap/redirectUrl/ac0cb032-4144-48b0-b4d9-aa5d9944a743?campId=4151')" height='435.0' width='470.0' x='0.0' y='0.0' source='http://adjingo.2cimple.com/content/151/Image/6290.jpg' ><keyframes><keyframe x="0.0" y="0.0" width="470.0" height="435.0" alpha="1.0" framenumber="0" /></keyframes></image></application>]]>
</renderingData>
</displayApp>
</adunit>
</girgit>
<panels/>
</Template>
<Skin url="http://adjingo.2cimple.com/cimple/assets/Skin.swf"/>
<Ads/>
</cimpleML>
```

I actually want the video and image links written after `videoId=` and `source=`, and I want to show them on my screen. However, from what I've tried, I'm unable to fetch the required data.

This is what I've tried:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    // If the current element name is equal to "cimpleML" then initialize the temporary dictionary.
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"cimpleML"]) {   
        self.dictTempDataStorage = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    // Keep the current element.
    self.currentElement = elementName;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"renderingData"]) { 
        // If the closing element equals to "renderingData" then the all the data inside it has been parsed and the dictionary should be added to the data array.
        [self.arrData addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.dictTempDataStorage]];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"adunit"]){
        // If the adunit element was found then store everything inside it.
        [self.dictTempDataStorage setObject:[NSString stringWithString:self.foundValue] forKey:@"adunitData"];
    }
}
```

Please help me get on the right track. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You might be complicating things. The XML parser parses top level elements. So just look out for `Campaign`, the `CDataBlock` needs to be parsed separately since it comes in as `NSData` object. Hence the recursive-looking code.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"%@", elementName);
    if([elementName isEqualTo:@"Campaign"])
    {
        NSString *videoId = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"videoId"];
        NSLog(@"video id is %@", videoId);
    }
    if([elementName isEqualTo:@"image"])
    {
        NSString *imageSource = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"source"];
        NSLog(@"image source is %@", imageSource);

    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSXMLParser *cDataParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock];
    cDataParser.delegate = self;
    [cDataParser parse];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lead_the_zeppelin! I understand your code, except for the fact that why `foundCDATA` is not being called? any idea? checked with breakpoints. application is not entering this function

Comment: @SHA did you verify it isn't like a spelling mistake? I ran the code before I pasted it here with your exact xml file.

Comment: Yes its exactly the same that I've copied. Infact, the `foundCharacters` method is being called, which is giving single characters one-by-one, which is obviously not what i need. 

I also read it in a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554089/problem-with-xml-parser-foundcdata-not-always-working) that sometimes `foundCharacters` is called instead of `foundCDATA`..

Confused

Comment: Yes @lead_the_zeppelin , as far as I know, it is in UTF-8 format

Comment: sorry I have no idea what's going on. Looks like a bug.